# <li> list to have same height in a row of 4 with constant height of biggest li?

Tags: jquery, html, css, angularjs

Currently I am generating list like this :

```
    <ul class='peerslistContentwithoutborderall' id="selectedPeerList">
    <li class="col col-90 togglepeerborderselectedall" style='float:left;' id="peerSelectList" ng-repeat="peers in data.selectedCompany" >
        <div id="{{index}}" ng-click="togglePeers(peers,peers.companyId,peers.companyName)" class="peersselectedclass peerslistContentdivtext">{{peers.companyName}}</div>
    </li></ul>
```

and with css I have set border,width and other properties so that list comes with 4 elements in each row with height as 44px.

The problem is if I have a bigger text the height goes down for that element only. Is there any solution in jquery or css so that after list generation the list element in a row takes height of biggest height element?

Comment: Put up the CSS that you are using at the moment.

Comment: further to cyber_rookie's comment, it is sometimes a good idea to offer a jsfiddle too so we can play with it and give you a quick answer back

Answer (score 1):

The logical answer would be to use CSS tables (not actual tables).

As follows:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: table;
  text-align: center;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}
li {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 4px
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi veniam!</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>lorem</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```